# Type checking on concatenated function arguments

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a `getLocale(obj, key, locale)` function that returns a key with a specific locale from an object, or returns a fallback locale variant.

I'd like to have type checking for this function, but I can't figure out how to merge the `key` and `locale` arguments to create the `keyof obj`:

My data:

```js
const data = {
    name_nl: 'Naam',
    name_en: 'Name',
}
```

The function:

```js
const allowedLangs = ['nl', 'en'] as const;
function getLocale<T extends Record<K, any>, K extends keyof any>(
    data: T,
    key: K,
    locale: typeof allowedLangs[number]
): T[K] | 'not-found' {
    return data[`${key}_${locale}`] || data[`${key}_en`] || 'not-found';
}
```

Calling the function:
`getLocale(data, 'name', 'nl'); // Naam`

TypeScript, however, complains that `Property 'name' is missing in type`, which is correct, since `K` is not directly a keyof `T` in my function, but the combination of `locale` and `key` are.

Is there a way to merge these arguments?

Comment: Can you change your data structure?

Comment: Not really; I image that you are thinking about something nested like `data.name.nl` and `data.name.en`?

Comment: Yup. :-) I don't think you can get type checking on the arguments to `getLocale` with your current structure.

Comment: Too bad; in this case I don't think this project will benefit from converting the data returned from an API-request, but I will think of this solution in the future for other functions.

Comment: Well, I could be wrong. :-) But I suspect you'll have to punt and just [accept any string](https://tsplay.dev/NByXgw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your function signature to solve this problem.

```
function getLocale<
  T extends Record<`${K}_${typeof allowedLangs[number]}`, any>, 
  K extends string
>(
    data: T,
    key: K,
    locale: typeof allowedLangs[number]
) {
    return data[`${key}_${locale}`] || data[`${key}_en`] || 'not-found';
}
```

Instead of using `keyof any` for `K`, just constrain it to `string`. We can use a template literal string type in the `Record`of `T` to constrain the key to start with `K` and end with `typeof allowedLangs[number]`.

You can just remove the return type of the function, so TypeScript can automatically infer it. The inferred return type will look like this:

```
T[`${K}_nl` | `${K}_en`] | T[`${K}_en`] | "not-found"
```

You now have complete validation when calling the function.

```
getLocale(data, 'name', 'nl');
getLocale(data, 'abc', 'nl'); // Error
getLocale(data, 'name', 'de'); // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDXMwIC2ApgPpgA2AXDAOQByCRtANDngSacWDQ0cVZYAvliyhIsBBQogA7sTgAZBGADmENDADatSqzo9aAXRgJNE6AG4xWAGYBXMMCgBLcDDXEoSkMGnEADzsACowxAAeUDxwmgBKxKAATnCBAAYAJBgA0sKkWVAAngAOxCB2ZjLyiirqENpgDoQARsRJxsJpLGZghQB83ezZ4VExmtBJrupYfQAU7LiIyDQhbHgwANbEhTTZa3iy-hTENEWl5ZWyCsqqGg1Nre1YAJSYCzBJ3g5JYPBICNpMhgtoU8llDgFOqYAD7Qv7IQFZEF5HhpGFwvQgKAAWjsICccFoNlEWC8Pj8AVmSwQ3T0AgMegotGeNjJviOxCp-1pCGawAZ+hZMAA9MKYABRJJJEBJUnedmU6m0ziCWlwQRC0USqUyoA)

Comment: your playground seems broken (half of the method only)

Comment: That is a very clear way to do this, with very clear validation-error messages as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

```
type Lang = 'nl' | 'en'
type Data<K extends string> = Record<`${K}_${Lang}`, any>

function getLocale<K extends string>(
    data: Data<K>,
    key: K,
    locale: Lang
): [K] | 'not-found' {
    return data[`${key}_${locale}`] || data[`${key}_en`] || 'not-found';
}


const l = getLocale({
    name_nl: 'Naam',
    name_en: 'Name',
}, 'name', 'nl');
```

Try out on [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgOwOZQLxQOQIDYagH0wgQwChRIoAROYOAHgGkoIAPYYgEwGcpvgATgEtkAPjRQAShADGAewGd6AAwAkAb0YBfAPob4yLcoA0URCFGlSAMwCuCGcCFyEUJBGAw5MuNghMWdi5efmExAApSKGioTlo4AC5qeKZRYyiYgGsIECTGdJiobG9fCCSDJFIASiSAbUYAXQJMBDlgAFprOXtOPHUM6IEPWwFXOLpatXVskF0NYp8-Iyb8QnG4SY0Z3WJlFcIsNs7uhF6AblItK1J5BH4iiXdPEr9w-sKEOABbCB0cJIwADk4N8MAUYp8fjpiADgT8wZdTFhvhAwS1cFULjcXNw5H4AHTFJDhbBVIA).

Answer (score 0):

You should change allowed langs to be an enum.
The way you are inferring the type is not correct

```
locale: typeof allowedLangs[number]
```

Should in fact be

```
locale: ArrElement<typeof allowedLangs>
```

The problem you are seeing though is on this line

```
key: K,
```

There isn't any better typing you can do than:
key: string